# How to build JSON string of particular format?

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I want to format a JSON string of below format using `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
{
"data":{"userName":"rrullo","password":"rrullo!"},
"meta":{"appId":"S3B9CU4R2B9JTXV9254Y","appVersion":"2.1.0","serverVersion":"1.1.0","platform":"iOS","deviceToken":"1234","tm_session_id":"BB0000001234"}
}
```

But I have no clue how to achieve this format though. Can someone help me please ......

Comment: 1) Learn the JSON syntax at json.org.  2) Create the outer dictionary to represent the outermost JSON "object".  3) Create the two inner dictionaries and insert them into the outer dictionary.  4) Serialize with NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fill two NSDictionaries with your 'meta' and 'data' info. Then add those into a main NSDictionary and then serialize using NSJsonSerialization

```
NSDictionary * metaDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
@"appId", @"S3B9CU4R2B9JTXV9254Y", @"appVersion", @"2.1.0", @"serverVersion", @"1.1.0", @"platform", @"iOS",..., nil];

NSDictionary * dataDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
@"userName", @"rrullo", @"password", @"rrullo!", nil];

NSDictionary * mainDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: 
@"data", dataDict, @"meta", metaDict, nil];
```

Now you can use NSJsonSerialization to convert that mainDict to a NSString

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mainDict 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Please mark this as the correct answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDictionary dictData = @{ @"UserName":@"rrullo", @"password":@"rrullo!"};
NSDictionary dictMeta = @{ @"appId":@"S3B9CU4R2B9JTXV9254Y", etc};
NSDictionary dictJSON = @{ @"data":dictData, @"meta":dictMeta };

NSError *error = nil; 
NSData *dataJSON = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictJSON 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataJSON encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick - Don't thank him if you don't understand what the code does.  When people try to do JSON stuff with copy/edit from other sources they almost always run amok quickly.